# How do I create a DocuSign Connect Configuration via Rest?

Tags: docusignapi

How do I create a DocuSign Connect Configuration via Rest?

Also what is the error message and max limit of DocuSign Connect Connections via Console or API I can create per Account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the writing of this question, the max number of custom connect configurations is 10.

Error message is below as well as a sample call:

```
{
  "errorCode": "MAX_CONNECT_CUSTOM_CONFIGURATION_EXCEEDED",
  "message": "Maximum number of connect custom configuration exceeded."
}
```

For reference here is the DocuSign Connect guide as of this questions https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_Connect_Service_Guide.pdf

Below is a sample of creating a DocuSign Connect Configuration via the REST API

```
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/[youraccountid]/connect 
Host: demo.docusign.net
X-DocuSign-Authentication: [add your info]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json


{
  "connectId": "1234",
  "urlToPublishTo": "http://www.yourdomain.com/listenerpage",
  "name": "Sample 1234",
  "allowEnvelopePublish": "true",
  "enableLog": "true",
  "includeDocuments": "false",
  "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "false",
  "requiresAcknowledgement": "true",
  "signMessageWithX509Certificate": "false",
  "useSoapInterface": "false",
  "includeTimeZoneInformation": "false",
  "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "true",
  "includeSenderAccountasCustomField": "true",
  "envelopeEvents": "completed",
  "recipientEvents": "",
  "userIds": "",
  "allUsers": "true",
  "includeCertSoapHeader": "false"
}
```